# Entity Framework Add() Is Updating Instead Of Inserting

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following function for adding an object to the database:

```
public void AddEnterpriseShare(Objects.FinancialTransactionEnterpriseShare share)
{
    _services.DbContext.FinancialTransactionEnterpriseShares.Add(share);
    _services.DbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

I call it as follows:

```
foreach (var enterprise in model.Enterprise)
{
    Service.FinancialTransactionServices.AddEnterpriseShare(new Data.Objects.FinancialTransactionEnterpriseShare()
    {
       ProfitLossId = profitLoss.Id,
       EnterpriseId = enterprise.Id,
       Percentage = enterprise.Percent,
       FinancialTransactionId = transaction.Id
   });
}
```

This loop should run 6 times, and add 6 new records into the database, one for each Id. If I step through this code though, I can see the record being created int he database.. then on second time through the loop, the original record is being updated, rather than a second record being inserted!

Why am I seeing this behaviour?

The entity class is as follows:

```
public class FinancialTransactionEnterpriseShare
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProfitLossId { get; set; }
    public int EnterpriseId { get; set; }
    public decimal Percentage { get; set; }
    public int FinancialTransactionId { get; set; }

    public ProfitLoss ProfitLoss { get; set; }
    public Enterprise Enterprise { get; set; }
    public FinancialTransaction FinancialTransaction { get; set; }
}

migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "FinancialTransactionEnterpriseShares",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                EnterpriseId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                FinancialTransactionId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                Percentage = table.Column<decimal>(nullable: false),
                ProfitLossId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_FinancialTransactionEnterpriseShares", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_FinancialTransactionEnterpriseShares_Enterprises_EnterpriseId",
                    column: x => x.EnterpriseId,
                    principalTable: "Enterprises",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.NoAction);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_FinancialTransactionEnterpriseShares_FinancialTransactions_FinancialTransactionId",
                    column: x => x.FinancialTransactionId,
                    principalTable: "FinancialTransactions",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.NoAction);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_FinancialTransactionEnterpriseShares_ProfitLosses_ProfitLossId",
                    column: x => x.ProfitLossId,
                    principalTable: "ProfitLosses",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.NoAction);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_FinancialTransactionEnterpriseShares_EnterpriseId",
            table: "FinancialTransactionEnterpriseShares",
            column: "EnterpriseId");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_FinancialTransactionEnterpriseShares_FinancialTransactionId",
            table: "FinancialTransactionEnterpriseShares",
            column: "FinancialTransactionId",
            unique: true);

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_FinancialTransactionEnterpriseShares_ProfitLossId",
            table: "FinancialTransactionEnterpriseShares",
            column: "ProfitLossId");
```

Comment: `Add` doesn't mean INSERT. It's the method that attaches an entity (possibly a detached entity) to the entity set. If the entity already has an ID and there *is* a matching row, it will be updated. What's the primary key for the `FinancialTransactionEnterpriseShare` entity? How is it set?

Comment: BTW the `AddEnterpriseShare` prevents EF from batching changes to a context and storing them all in a single go. It actually *degrades* the ORM's functionality and performance. It prevents it from acting as a Unit-of-Work and would require explicit transactions with the corresponding scalability penalty to bring that functionality back

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Id is the primary key, and it's set to auto-increment

Comment: @GavinCoates Please add `FinancialTransactionEnterpriseShare` model class code to the question please.

Comment: @TanvirArjel - done.

Comment: @TanvirArjel - the AddEnterpriseShare() function is at the top of my post

Comment: @GavinCoates Post the DbContext configuration too. The class doesn't have any EF attributes so nothing says that `Id` is a key or that it's generated by the database

Comment: @GavinCoates it's *still* a bad idea to use that method though. Add all 6 entities and call SaveChanges once. There's no reason to perfom individual inserts one by one and pay the network roundtrip cost 6 times

Comment: @GavinCoates If primary is key auto-increment then it should not be happened! Don't know what is happening in your case.

Comment: Consider providing [mcve]. With the current information it should not happen.

Comment: Still it's not a verifiable example - lacks other involved entities and fluent configuration. The migration shows that `FinancialTransactionId` is set to be *unique*, which should be causing the behavior in question. I was expecting something like that, but can't tell you the exact case w/o seeing the missing part of the model / configuration - the problem is definitely in a code not shown here.

Comment: @IvanStoev `FinancialTransactionId` is a foreign key to another table (FinancialTransactions). `Id` is unique here, as that is the primary key. I'm not sure what other code to show, there isn't really anything else to show, other than the code for the related tables.

Comment: @IvanStoev - sorry, i see what you mean now about the "unique" on that field. It certainly shouldn't be there! EDIT: Removing it doesn't seem to make any difference though

Comment: You should find and remove the code *causing* it, not modifying the generated migration. There must be a reason for that unique index - most likely discovered/configured one-to-one relationship instead of one-to-many. So, what other code to show - `FinancialTransaction` class and `OnModelCreating`.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Ivan Stoevs comments above, I have now found the issue.

The `FinancialTransaction` class contains a reference to the `FinancialTransactionEnterpriseSplit` class - this reference was set as 1:1 rather than being 1:*. As a result of this, when generated, the `FinancialTransactionId` field was being created with the unique flag set to true.

Updating the code to use `ICollection<FinancialTransactionEnterpriseSplit>` in `FinancialTransaction` solved the issue, causing the field to be created correctly.